# generator-angular-fullstack route issue

Tags: angularjs, express, generator, yeoman

I'm having a problem with the generator-angular-fullstack yeoman skeleton. I can't figure out what is serving up the index.html file for the base URL (http://localhost:9001). The only route I can find that seems probable is pasted below. If I add a console.log() or set break points with node-inspector, it doesn't seem to be the one getting called. I even commented out the res.sendFile line and index.html is still served up.

```
  app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
    });
```

I want to add some middleware to whatever is serving up the index.html file.

Comment: I found it. It was the following line in the express.js config file:
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));

Answer (score 0):

It's in the very next app.use line.